# Bind Data gives ID along with other data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-bindings

I'm trying to bind data using this code:

```
    {{company.category}} | {{company.locations[0]}}
    {{company.company_name}}
```

The output is:

```
    [{"id":1,"category":"Advertising and Agencies"},{"id":2,"category":"Arts and Music"},{"id":3,"category":"Client Services"},{"id":4,"category":"Consumer"},{"id":5,"category":"Education"}] | {"id":1,"cities":"Delhi"}
    Microsft Corp
```

I don't know why there's all this curly brackets and id. Where am I going wrong? I got the company_name correctly shown.

Comment: Looking at the information you provided, I would say your model contains a list in `company.category` and that is what is being displayed.

Comment: This is from the network captured:
> category: [{id: 1, category: "Advertising and Agencies"}, {id: 2, category: "Arts and Music"},…]
0: {id: 1, category: "Advertising and Agencies"}
1: {id: 2, category: "Arts and Music"}
2: {id: 3, category: "Client Services"}

Comment: your are printing whole array and object that's it is showing like this,where your name is a single arribute so it is showing correctly..Problem is with your represtation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [JSON](http://json.org/) notation to describe a javascript object.

As to why that's displaying: it looks like `company.category` contains an array of objects.

Fix this by specifying the object and property out of the array that you want to display.

For example:

`company.category[0].category`

=> That's some really confusing property naming by the way, you should probably name this more logically to avoid confusion.

For the code after the `|`, that's also just an object, display the property name you need, for example:

`{{company.locations[0].cities}}`

Comment: Was scratching my head for over an hour!! Thank You so much :)

Will accept your answer in 7 minutes when it allows me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `company` should be your model. Then on this you need to have properties of `category`, `company_name` and an array of `locations`. The `id` looks to be a property on your model and will most likely be the key that makes each record unique. Then you will be able to bind. the curly braces `{{ }}` are so that angular knows it's something that it needs to know about and a way to separate the angular from regular html etc.